# How can I see a history of the terminal output, not just commands entered?

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to do some debugging in Android and I am running a live logcat in the Terminal, but the problem is that there is too much information generated so that when I am finished and try to copy all the information received by choosing "Select All" and then "Copy" a lot of the early output which is produced isn't copied. I was aware of `history`, but that just provides a list of commands that have previously been entered, not the output.

Can I see a history of all the output that the terminal gives, or perhaps can I have the terminal save as a text file all the output that it is producing?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24283097/reusing-output-from-last-command-in-bash. So it doesn't really seem possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can append all logs to a text file by redirecting output. But this requires each command is executed like this (this will catch both `stdout` & `stderr`)

```
command >>file.txt 2>&1
```

OR

You can record screencasts of terminal, since it stores screencast in text file, you can use that. Its called [shelr](https://github.com/antono/shelr)

Files are stored in `~/.local/share/shelr/`

Source: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/04/how-to-record-and-share-terminal-screencasts-quickly/

*Note: I have no idea of android development.This answer is based on shell scripting.*

Comment: `shelr` is Awesome

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem the other day, and I found this solution:
http://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/save-logcat-to-a-text-file

Maybe it's not the best thing you could do I think this is what you were asking for.